# Trying to Convert HTML form into JSON but returning empty

Tags: html, json

I've been trying to convert an HTML form into Json.  When I submit the form my alert is just returning an empty array.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the form

```
<form action="" method="post" name="myForm">
Code (xxxx-xxx):<input type="text" name="drugcode" /> <br/>
<p><input type="submit" onClick='submitform()' /></p>
</form>
```

And here is the javascript

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language ="javascript" type = "text/javascript" >

function submitform() {

var formData = JSON.stringify($("form[name*='myForm']").serializeArray());
alert(formData);

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "serverUrl",
  data: formData,
  success: function(){},
  dataType: "json",
  contentType : "application/json",
 processData: false
 });
}

</script>
```

All that this is returning is:

[]

EDIT:
It now returns:

[{"name":"code","value":"1234"},{"name":"blah","value":"4321"}]

how would I would I have it return:
{"code":"1234","value":"4321"}

Answer (score 2):

$("#myForm")  is not going to match the form for you.  # specifies an id.  You need to match on the name:

```
$( "form[name='myForm']" )...
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (was also posting!). You could also use `<form id="myForm">` to get the same result.

Comment: Perfect Thank you!

Comment: Mark as accepted, I'm currently grinding on stack overflow!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use simple javascript and select the form using

```
document.querySelector("form[name='myForm']")
```

or

```
document.forms[0]
```